# Using Kotlin/Native, how can I execute an external OS executable or $PATH command and interact with its stdin, stdout, and stderr streams?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm working on a proof of concept for a command line tool written in Kotlin/Native, as it seems to be an ideal language and runtime for cross-platform binaries.

This command line tool needs to regularly interact with operating system executables, commands and/or shell functions in the os user $PATH or shell environment.  However, I don't see any examples in [kotlin-native samples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples) or documentation anywhere that might indicate how to:

- execute an operating system executable or $PATH command
- obtain the execution's return code (integer)
- ensure the executed process's stdin, stdout and stderr file descriptor streams can be represented as OutputStream and InputStreams respectively

In JVM-land, we'd use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` for all of this, but that's apparently not available in Kotlin/Native.

I found the cinterop/posix `platform.posix.system` function, but that doesn't give you access to the process's streams.

In my web research, I found a really nice C [tutorial](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/02/17/how-do-i-call-a-program-in-c-with-pipes/) that indicates the only clean way to do this is with `fork` and `dup2` and such, but it's not clear to me if or how that would translate to Kotlin/Native code.

Comment: Hello! AFAIK, both `fork()` and `dup2` got to be in the `platform.posix.*`, distributed with the compiler. Are you sure, that this is not enough?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I know they're there, but I've never used them. As a result, it's not obvious to me how to 1) actually use them effectively with proper error handling in a C+Kotlin best-practices manner and 2) wrap them to enable something similar to ProcessBuilder.

Comment: any news on this? is it meanwhile possible to exec Process with kotlin native??

Comment: @DirkHoffmann unfortunately no.  I didn't have time to implement this myself and there aren't native solutions yet that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I did some play around with kotlin native and succeded to do a posix exec command for jvm, mac, unix and (untested) windows...

https://github.com/hoffipublic/minimal_kotlin_multiplatform

target common

```kotlin
fun String.executeCommand(
    redirectStderr: Boolean = true
): String? = MppProcess.executeCommand(this, redirectStderr)

interface IMppProcess {
    fun executeCommand(
        command: String,
        redirectStderr: Boolean = true
    ): String?
}

expect object MppProcess : IMppProcess {
    override fun executeCommand(
        command: String,
        redirectStderr: Boolean
    ): String?
}
```

target jvm

```kotlin
actual object MppProcess : IMppProcess {
    actual override fun executeCommand(
        command: String,
        redirectStderr: Boolean
    ): String? {
        return runCatching {
            ProcessBuilder(command.split(Regex("(?<!(\"|').{0,255}) | (?!.*\\1.*)")))
                //.directory(workingDir)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                .apply { if (redirectStderr) this.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE) }
                .start().apply { waitFor(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                .inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        }.onFailure { it.printStackTrace() }.getOrNull()
    }
}
```

target mac/unix/windows

```kotlin
import kotlinx.cinterop.refTo
import kotlinx.cinterop.toKString
import platform.posix.fgets
import platform.posix.pclose
import platform.posix.popen

actual object MppProcess : IMppProcess {
    actual override fun executeCommand(
        command: String,
        redirectStderr: Boolean
    ): String? {
        val commandToExecute = if (redirectStderr) "$command 2>&1" else command
        val fp = popen(commandToExecute, "r") ?: error("Failed to run command: $command")

        val stdout = buildString {
            val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
            while (true) {
                val input = fgets(buffer.refTo(0), buffer.size, fp) ?: break
                append(input.toKString())
            }
        }

        val status = pclose(fp)
        if (status != 0) {
            error("Command `$command` failed with status $status${if (redirectStderr) ": $stdout" else ""}")
        }

        return stdout
    }
}
```

only did execute ls by now, but it works.

Comment: Dirk - did you have a chance to get it to work with `fork` and `dup2` per the "best practices" cited in that article?  If not, why did you choose the above approach?